# Selenium Webdriver не могу найти ссылку по тексту

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[Ссылка на сайт](https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/dortbey-insaat/meydan-eryaman)

Не могу найти ссылку по тексту `İnceleme` (Турецкий)

Код элемента:

```
<a 
    href="https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/meydan-eryaman-review-2" 
    class="b-complex-sub-menu__item js-complex-sub-menu swiper-slide" 
    style="margin-right: 15px;">
        İnceleme
</a>
```

Код:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("İnceleme")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, `find_element_by_link_text` почему-то не работает. Возможно, дело в кодировке. Как вариант, можно вытащить текст через `contains(text(), 'İnceleme')`.

```
driver.get('https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/dortbey-insaat/meydan-eryaman')

res = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='b-complex-sub-menu__item js-complex-sub-menu swiper-slide' and contains(text(), 'İnceleme')]")[-1].get_attribute('href')
print(res)

# https://www.hurriyetemlak.com/projeler/meydan-eryaman-review-2
```